# Swift BigInt to [UInt8]

Tags: ios, swift, integer, bigint

I am using swift 4 and am using this implementation of BigInt: https://github.com/attaswift/BigInt

I noticed there are no native methods to convert a BigInt or NSDecimalNumber into a [UInt8], do any of you know a good implementation of this as I have not been able to find one.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BigUInt` has a

```
/// Return a `Data` value that contains the base-256 representation of this integer,
/// in network (big-endian) byte order.
public func serialize() -> Data
```

method (see [Data Conversion.swift](https://github.com/attaswift/BigInt/blob/master/sources/Data%20Conversion.swift#L80)), so what you can do is

```
let bi: BigInt = ...
let bytes = Array(BigUInt(bi).serialize())
```