# I need some method to convert BigInt to Bytes array like in java in swift

Tags: java, swift, biginteger, bigint

I nedd to convert BigInt to bytes array like in java in swift.
attaswift/BigInt can convert only UInt without signing. What can i do on swift? How to convert or add signing to bytes array? 0 in top left byte working not always.

Java code

```
java.math.BigInteger.toByteArray()
```

semi worked Swift code

```
BigUInt.serialize()
```

My question is more complicated than this question([Swift BigInt to [UInt8]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987069/swift-bigint-to-uint8)). I need to consider the sign in the byte array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/48987069/1187415

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift BigInt to \[UInt8\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987069/swift-bigint-to-uint8)

Comment: @RudyVelthuis , If I use this method, then I transform BigUInt without a signed, but I need an array with a signed(BigInt). I can add 0 in top left byte, but this working not always.

Comment: Only add a 0 top byte if the current top byte >= 0x80 and the original BigInt is positive. Add a 0xFF top byte if the current top byte <= 0x7F and the original BigInt is negative.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis , Thanks you.
Can you help with the reverse method?

Comment: @O.Shulzhenko: sorry, no. But that would be another question.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, thank you. When i make my serialize() other bytes(not first) is like UInt(0xFF is 255) or Int(0xFF is -1)?

Comment: @O.Shulzhenko: and that is another question. But OK. 0xFF is what you interpret it to be. It can be interpreted as -1 or as 255. In this case, you insert it at the top to make the value of all bytes together two's complement negative (because the previous top byte was <= 0x7F, so positive). The same with a top byte >= 0x80: that will be intepreted as negative too (top bit set), so if the oringinal BigInteger is positive, you must add a 0 at the top, to make the entire value positive. But never forget that signed or unsigned is merely a matter of interpretation. Read up about two's complement.

Comment: The other bytes are simply carriers for the bits of the BigInteger. If it was coded properly, then you should get the same values as in other languages, which is generally [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) (even if the internal representation may be different). Most BigInteger implementations I know *pretend* to be two's complement and will accept or produce byte arrays in two's complement format, although not always with the same endianness (Java: always big-endian, .NET usually little-endian). Internally, they often use sign-magnitude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I made the right extension code.

Please write if you see any mistakes.

```
extension BigInt {

public func serialize() -> Data {
    var array = Array(BigUInt.init(self.magnitude).serialize())

    if array.count > 0 {
        if self.sign == BigInt.Sign.plus {
            if array[0] >= 128 {
                array.insert(0, at: 0)
            }
        } else if self.sign == BigInt.Sign.minus {
            if array[0] <= 127 {
                array.insert(255, at: 0)
            }
        }
    }

    return Data.init(bytes: array)
}

public init(_ data: Data) {
    var dataArray = Array(data)
    var sign: BigInt.Sign = BigInt.Sign.plus

    if dataArray.count > 0 {
        if dataArray[0] >= 128 {
            sign = BigInt.Sign.minus

            if dataArray.count > 1 {
                if dataArray[0] == 255, dataArray.count > 1 {
                    dataArray.remove(at: 0)
                } else {
                    dataArray[0] = UInt8(256 - Int(dataArray[0]))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    let magnitude = BigUInt.init(Data.init(bytes: dataArray))

    self .init(sign: sign, magnitude: magnitude)
}
```

}